# Broken Images and Style

Tags: urls, migration

After moving Wordpress to another account, the style and images are broken. I have tried disabling plugins, checking and updating "Uploads" folder in Database, checking folders and files permissions, re-saving Permalinks, adding codes to wp-config... None has fixed the problem. Screenshot here: https://prnt.sc/v9mxqt

Any suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The URL for a media item is stored in the database for that item. The URL includes the domain name.

If you move a site to a new domain, the URLs in the posts database are not necessarily changed. (And there are often other items that might not be updated to the new domain name.)

Your best bet is to use a search and replace plugin to search for olddomain.com and replace with newdomain.com . I've had good luck using the "Better Search and Replace" plugin to do this on sites that I have moved.

Of course, back up your database before any such action, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the contributions!. I had to replace the "wp-admin" and "wp-includes" folders with fresh ones downloaded from Wordpress.org. I think the issue was in one of those folders, but couldn't find it was exactly. But replacing those 2 folders resolved the problem.

Comment: Glad it's fixed. But it may be that your media doesn't work due to old URLs. Check a media items's URL (click on an older media item and look on the right side of the screen). Open that URL in another window, and see if the image shows up.
I'd still recommend the search/replace process to ensure there aren't any instances of the old domain anywhere in the database.
And a 'checkmark' and upvote is always appreciated if my answer was correct. It helps others with similar problems.